# How to get files to copy from S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Need some help with cp command in AWS CLI. I am trying to copy files from S3 bucket to a local folder.  The command I used seems to have run successfully in Powershell, but the folder is still empty.

Command:

`aws s3 cp s3://<my bucket path> <my local destination> --exclude "*" --include "*-20201023*" --recursive --dryrun`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--dryrun` parameter prohibits the command from actually copying anything.  It just shows you what would happen.  Try removing that parameter and running the command.